# Core Data: Many-to-many Predicate NOT not working

Tags: core-data, ios6, nspredicate

Im trying to make a predicate for filtering on a many to many relationship. I have a Message object with many Labels as a relationship.

I can do the following:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY labels.labelId == 4"];
```

and I will only get the messages that have the Label with the labelId 4. But If I do

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE labels.labelId == 4"];
```

This will give me every singe Message object I have, even if they have a relationship with a Label with the labelId 4. Why is that? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that "NONE" or "NOT ANY" does not work as expected in Core Data predicates. Both predicates

```
 NONE labels.labelId == 4
 NOT (ANY labels.labelId == 4)
```

actually return the same result as

```
 ANY labels.labelId != 4
```

which is not how I understand the documentation. As a workaround, you can use a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(labels, $x, $x.labelId == 4).@count == 0"]
```

Comment: Worked in my situation, seemed to only be a problem on initial fetch, updates were handled correctly with the predicate... seems to be an apple bug to me.

Comment: I have the same issue with `NONE` or `NOT ANY`. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @fabb: No, I can't tell you *why* "NONE" or "NOT ANY" do not work as expected.

Comment: I'll file an Apple Radar, and I suggest everyone experiencing this issue does the same.

Comment: Filed rdar://19365874